# Magento2: redirection from Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect

We have already know that **How to redirect from an Observer** for magento 1.x version.

but for **magento 2**,we does not know ***How to forcefully do redirection from an observer***.

I have done google ,but does not get any answer.

Comment: Did You found solution for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yup, i have find **a solution by myself by doing a research**

If you want to do that then on `__construct()` function of *`your class observer`*,***you must inject two classes***.

- First, **`\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory`** which  **responsible for
  redirection**,
- Another  class **`\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface`** which will make url
  for that redirection.
- Then create object for `ResponseFactory`  ,and using
  ***`setRedirect($YourUrl)->sendResponse();`*** redirect to your wished url.

---

### Observer

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class [YourClass] implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
        ......
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        ......
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
        $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

### Example:

Here i am write an example of that  redirection.

Basically `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event,i was try to forcefully **redirect to contact us.**

**Here the observer code:**

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Devamit\Mgoto\Observer;
> use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
> use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
>
> class Challo implements ObserverInterface {
>     protected $_responseFactory;
>     protected $_url;
>
>     public function __construct(
>
>         \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
>         \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
>     ) {
>         $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
>         $this->_url = $url;
>     }
>   
>     public function execute(Observer $observer) {
>         $event = $observer->getEvent();
>         
>             $myfile = fopen("var/log/debug.log", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
>           fwrite($myfile, 'Amitber',true);
>           fclose($myfile);
>       // $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect('www.google.com')->sendResponse();
>            $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('contact/index/index');
>           $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
>       return $this;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: are you working at early morning 4 a.m ? just unbelievable. there is lot to learn from you.

Comment: Hi @amit , I am using 'sales_order_place_before' event and order is placed using ajax. When I use the above code, it do not redirects but it renders the response. I do not want that. can you please suggest a way to redirect to a page when form is saved using ajax. Thanks

Comment: Don't use exit(); because Magento EcgM2 coding standard show error "Use of exit language construct is discouraged."

Comment: we should not use exit() according to Magento 2 coding standards.

Comment: ya. i know that i will edit

Comment: @AmitBera If you're not calling exit, you should use `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http` as a constructor argument instead. It won't work when using the factory class.

Comment: Thanks  for  advising.  I will  check    and update the answers

Comment: If you are using a predispatch event then you need to inject \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag  in your constructor and inside your observer function use $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true); to tell magento to stop processing the further events and then you can use redirectInterface to redirect user whereever you want.

Comment: Without `exit();` it is working for you? @AmitBera

Comment: bro, i will cross check it  tonight

Comment: Ok, I am using in plugin but it is not working for me :( and `exit()` is not good to use. @PrincePatel  @Amit

Comment: Can anyone share the solution?

Comment: *Note* : You cannot use this method (using `ResponseFactory`) if you observe `controller_action_postdispatch_*` events

Comment: @AmitBera, is there any way to redirect with parameter?

Answer (score 12):

injecting the `\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag` and `$this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);`is the way of forcing Magento to stop processing further events and redirect from an observer specially in the case of using  predispatch event.

Here is the sample code

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost\Interceptor $controller_action */
    $controller_action = $observer->getData( 'controller_action' );
    $parameters = $controller_action->getRequest()->getParams();
    $session = $this->customerSession;

    if({yourcondition}){


        // setting an action flag to stop processing further hierarchy
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);



        /// redirecting back to its referred url
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirectInterface->getRefererUrl());
        $session->setCustomerFormData($parameters);

    }

    return $this;


}
```

Comment: it is a good solution. It will be better if you will add full class in your solution.

Answer (score 8):

Above answer is not working for me I have updated my observer code

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $params = []; 

        // If you want to redirect with data
        // $url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('checkout/cart/index',$params);

        $url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');

        $observer->getControllerAction()
                    ->getResponse()
                    ->setRedirect($url);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace Adnan\Redirect\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * Class Example
 *
 * phpcs:disable Generic.Files.LineLength
 *
 * @package Adnan\Example\Redirect
 */
class Example implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    private $actionFlag;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface   $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {

        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Stop further processing if your condition is met
        $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        // then in last redirect
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->url->getUrl("[FrontName]/[Controller]/[Action]"));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Remember to use `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` to generate URL otherwise, you will not be redirected to a top-level structure, e.g. if you are not using `UrlInterface` and want to redirect from "checkout" with "a/b/c" then it will process "checkout/a/b/c".

You have an option to use `\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag`, it will stop further processing of observers.

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on a form that use Ajax for request processing. I send the response in the form of json and based on Ajax request success/failure, I use **window.location.href** to redirect on a page.

You can pass the required URL in the json and can access it in the response using dot (.) operator.

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    data:$("#form-id").serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    showLoader: true,
    success:function(result) {
        if(result.status == true) {
            if (result.product_url) {
                window.location.href = result.product_url;
            }
        }
    },
    error:function(xhr,textStatus,thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: The question was about Observer/backend, not frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use case, most of proposed solutions have problem: Redirects might be cached, due to other places where the response is set.

Scenario: You do a redirect based on login status -> even after the logs in, the protected page they tried to access before the login still redirects, because the 302 response is cached for one day.

I ended up in doing this:

```
    if (!$isCustomerLoggedIn && !in_array($actionFullName, self::ALLOWED_ROUTES)) {
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getResponse();
        $response->clearHeaders();
        $this->redirect->redirect($response, 'customer/account/login');
    }
```

**EDIT** Does not work --> clearHeaders kills the FPC - working on an alternative solution

**EDIT2** Better solution:

```
        /**
         * @var $action Action
         */
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

        /**
         * @var $response \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
         */
        $response = $action->getResponse();
        $response->clearHeaders()->setNoCacheHeaders();
        $this->redirect->redirect($response, 'customer/account/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adnan** Answer worked for me.

In event.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xs  d">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="Name-Your-Observer" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\[YourClassName]" />
    </event>
</config>
```

After that in Observer Folder Create YourClassName.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class [YourClassName] implements ObserverInterface    
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    private $actionFlag;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface   $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {

        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Stop further processing if your condition is met
        $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        // then in last redirect
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->url->getUrl("[route]/[controller]/[action]"));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps and need all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

> **After many solutions tried I found one working code. Here I used the controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_save event which is working fine.**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;

class ObserverClassName implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_urlInterface;
    protected $actionFlag;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ) {
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('cms/page/index');
        $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $response = $controller->getResponse();
        return $response->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use header("Location: ".$storeUrl."/register-success");
in your observer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/181950)

Comment: ok sir.Actually I am new to stack overflow.