# Magento2 : Redirect from observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.1, redirect

I have already implemented [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112993/magento2-redirection-from-observer) solution , but it is not working for me

I am trying to redirect customer after login to different page rather than my account

What i tried

**\app\code\Mycompany\Customerhomepage\etc\frontend\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="mycompany_customerhomepage_customer_login" instance="Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Observer\Customerlogin"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**\app\code\Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Observer\Customerlogin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory;

/**
 * Class customerlogin
 * @package Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Observer
 */
class customerlogin implements ObserverInterface{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * @param UrlInterface $url
     * @param ResponseFactory $responseFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customerhomepage/index/landing');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
        die();

    }
}
```

It also exhibiting in variable behavior , sometime it redirects sometime it does not

Comment: We can use `controller_action_predispatch` event: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131706/magento-2-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-if-not-logged-in/131713#131713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **ResponseInterface** did the trick for me

```
namespace Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

/**
 * Class customerlogin
 * @package Mycompany\Customerhomepage\Observer
 */
class customerlogin implements ObserverInterface{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;
    /**
     * @param UrlInterface $url
     * @param ResponseFactory $responseFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_response = $response;

    }
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customerhomepage/index/landing');

        $this->_response->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove `\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory` as that's not being used in the `Observer`.

Comment: The solution didn't work for me.