# Best way to redirect from observer in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, third-party-module

I am trying to redirect from observer but it does passing in Magento marketplace validations.

Tried.

1. `$this->redirect->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl);`
2. `$this->_response->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
    $this->_messageManager->addError($message);`
3. `$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();`

I need a redirect method which does not depend on exit and die because magento does not allow that.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart.php#L113  This might help you

Comment: Please check this URL https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112993/magento2-redirection-from-observer

Answer (score 2):

The codes you have mentioned in question do redirect effectively. Since **Magento is not allowing** to use redirect methods depending upon exit and die I had search for such methods which are already being used in **magento core's observer for redirect purpose.**

I have found few of them which I'm going to list:

**1. Magento\Captcha\Observer\CheckForgotpasswordObserver.php**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
) {
    ...
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
}

/**
 * Check Captcha On Forgot Password Page
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $formId = 'user_forgotpassword';
    $captchaModel = $this->_helper->getCaptcha($formId);
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->captchaStringResolver->resolve($controller->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Incorrect CAPTCHA'));
            $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), '*/*/forgotpassword');
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Since it is included in core file I think this could be the one that can be used.

**2. You may see the same method is used in `Magento\Captcha\Observer\CheckContactUsFormObserver` and `module-captcha/Observer/CheckUserEditObserver.php` as well.**

Comment: Thanks for your response i will try and get back to you with the outcome

Comment: Sure. Let us know the outcome.

Comment: This solution seems to be working with all other Php version -7.0.21

Environment: Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 7.0.21, Magento Platform - 2.0.17 CE Varnish, Sampla Data
Command:
vendor/bin/phpunit
Installation issue:
http://magento.dev/gear.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.

Fac

Comment: Okay. Is this the solution you were looking for? It would be great to know if it works. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yeah this extension is working but having the same issue which was previously in my extension

Comment: Okay. I'll see more into it. What magento extension validator warns or says?

Answer (score 0):

> **You can get code from the below file path**

```
vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-ui/Model/RequestHandler.php
```

> **Here you can see the processError() method where the whole redirect code is written. you can follow the same code in your custom file. below is a sample of how to add the same code in your Observer file.**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;

class ObserverClassName implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_urlInterface;
    protected $actionFlag;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ) {
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('YourPath'); // Like cms/page/index
        $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $response = $controller->getResponse();
        return $response->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl);
    }
}
```

**Note: In the core where this code is working. They are used controller_action_predispatch event. you can check ReCaptcha related core modules in a vendor.**