# Redirect Url in magento2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect

How to redirect from `Observer` in `Magento2` ? I am using the below code:

```
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
$action = $this->_request->getActionName();
$this->_actionFlag->set($action, \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
$controller->getResponse()->setRedirect('sales/order/address', array('address_id' => $addressId));
return $this;
```

**event.xml**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_addressSave">
    <observer name="verify_cod" instance="XXX\Ccc\Observer\Pincode" />
</event>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to do redirects on observer:

```
 $url = $this->urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login');
            $observer->getControllerAction()
                ->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($url);
```

Comment: Did you added urlInterface on the constructor and deleted var/generation? 


Try to use  header php function , just for testing purposes
header('Location: urlhere');
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Also might be worth to look at these links 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112993/magento2-redirection-from-observer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902212/magento2-redirect-from-observer

https://webkul.com/blog/redirect-controller-observer-magento2/

Comment: Its working for me when i use exit()

Comment: @PriyaM try to use return instead of exit();

Comment: but why use this

Comment: To stop executing the other code that is coming after your observer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use constructor for it.

Below code working for me.

```
namespace ......

class something
{
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,

) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;

}

 public function execute()
{
   $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/');
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: No,Its not observer.php but constructor for redirection is same for all.

Comment: why.. use exit() in this place