# Magento 2.4.2: redirection from Observer not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.4.3

I am getting 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'.
I tried solution from this link:
[Magento2: redirection from Observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112993/magento2-redirection-from-observer)

```
 public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'sales/order/history');
}
```

**Edit**:

This issue was coming because I have used contoller predispatch events so every controller is redirecting to 'sales/order/history', which include sales/order/history controller, which results in too many Redirects

Comment: Hello Atul,
Can you please tell me which observer you are using?

Comment: controller_action_predispatch - I am using this event.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you two ways to redirect from the observer.

1)

```
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');
```

2. 

```
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
$url = $this->getUrl('customer/account/login'); //Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
$controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

Example

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Captcha\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckForgotpasswordObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $redirect;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect to login page
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Checked this one,

```
protected $actionFlag; 
protected $redirect; 

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect

) {
    $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), '*/*/edit');
}
```

This will work for you,
Happy Coding

Comment: it's not working for me. showing error - 'too many redirects'

Comment: Okay, Can you please tell me which event you are using?

Comment: controller_action_predispatch - I am using this event. also please test on magento 2.4.3. as this was working before on previous versions.

Comment: I thing you have to used controller_action_postdispatch because of if you used predispatch it means, Your observer call before, after you observer again magento need to going to check main controller action, So it'll display to many redirect,

Comment: Okay, Let me check,

Comment: controller_action_postdispatch - even after using this, I am getting same issues.

Comment: Really ? Can you please try to remove the redirection code from POST dispatch and check where it'll redirect by default and tell me

Comment: if possible can you please send me your observer file?

Comment: code  added in question, please check.

Comment: I updated the answer, Use that one, It'll worked

Comment: Just change your redirection controller action,

Comment: I checked in magento 2.4.3 latest version its worked, If you get issue let me know

Comment: please check my updated code, Even that is not working for me.

Comment: Thanks Tushar for help, I don't have enough reputation to upvote,

Comment: Upvote not matter Atul, I happy, I helped you,

Comment: @Tushar it doesn't work for me. facing the same issue of too many redirects. Using Magento 2.4.5 p1. I'd appreciate the help.